# yntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ejs

In my EJS file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>To do List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <% if (kindOfDay === “Saturday” || kindOfDay === “Sunday”) { %>
          <h1 style="color: green"><%= kindOfDay %> List </h1>
        <% } else { %>
          <h1 style="color: blue"><%= kindOfDay %> List </h1>
        <% } %>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When the code is:

```
    <h1>it's a<%= kindOfDay %> List </h1>
```

it works, but now it shows:

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in /Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/views/list.ejs while compiling ejs

> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
> https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
> Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
> at new Function ()
> at Template.compile (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12)
> at Object.compile (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:396:16)
> at handleCache (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:233:18)
> at tryHandleCache (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:16)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
> at View.render (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
> at Function.render (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (/Users/annezhang/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1017:7)

I’m not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_". What do you want your code to do, and what it does instead? Notice, that smart quotes are not valid, use `"`s instead.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I described it clearly

Comment: Did you set view engine to ejs?

Comment: Yep～I write the code:
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
in my JS file